Конфликт имен docker контейнеров
У меня на сервере есть 2 docker контейнера, с одинаковым именем database. По понятным причинам после запуска второго одноименного контейнера database, docker выдает мне следующую ошибку:
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/database" is already in use by container "uuid". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Хотел бы узнать, как можно "красиво" решить эту проблему. Может быть можно запустить несколько экземпляров docker.service? Или существуют уже готовые решения?
Примечание: Да, я могу просто переименовать docker контейнер и запустить как есть. Но в моем проекте довольно много упоминаний daatabase контейнера, да и было бы на много удобнее, если все database контейнеры назывались одинаково
